# vim folds open up when giving an unmatched opening brace/parenthesis

Tags: vim, folding

I often come across the situation where I have lots of lines folded and I am writing, say a new block of code, above these folds. As soon as I type a '{', all the folds below open up. Even though it is legitimate that vim does this, it is irritating to close all the folds again. Is there a way around this situation?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with a default vim installation and a simple Java file...

Comment: I also can't reproduce this.  Curious, do you have `showmatch` turned on?  Does this setting affect the behavior?

Comment: @r.v I wonder what do you have in your `foldmarker`?

Comment: @krakover, @Randy Morris I believe that you can reproduce this behavior with default vim setup if you will do the following: start vim with `vim -u NONE -c 'set nocompatible fdm=marker fmr={,}' -c "call setline('.', repeat(['{', '}'], 3))"` and then typing `zoo{`.

Comment: @Randy Morris `showmatch` is off. @ZyX I am using `foldmethod=syntax`. `fmr={{{,}}}` but I think it is not used here.

Comment: @r.v `fmr` - yes, it is not used. But cause is just the same: when you type `{` you make all blocks below be contained in the current block. As current block is open, all new contained blocks appear open too. I don't know any workarounds. Personally I use `fdm=marker` and use only markers of the form `{{{N` (and, sometimes, with closing `}}}N`). In case you specify foldlevel explicitely with `N` it does not autoopen folds.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it using [this vimtip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text).

Little excerpt of the tip description:

> If you are using any sort of automatic folding method, be it marker, syntax, or expression folding, inserting text that starts a fold will automatically open all folds beneath the insertion point. This can be very annoying. To get around this, you can temporarily switch to a manual fold method when entering insert mode, and switch back when leaving it.

The trick is to set the `foldmethod` to `manual` when editing starts:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * if !exists('w:last_fdm') | let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
```

When you're done with editing, reset `foldmethod` to it's original value:

```
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * if exists('w:last_fdm') | let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm | unlet w:last_fdm | endif
```